# Stripe checkout summery is missing in payments

Tags: node.js, reactjs

After successfully implementing stripe credit card subscription payment in frontend (react) and backend (node) there is the checkout summary missing in the payment details page on stripe. Customer creation and payment are shown as "completed" or "successful" so at first glance there doesn't seem to be a problem. But it is strange to have no subscription reference on the payment details page.

I use @stripe/react-stripe-js and stripe.subscriptions.create({}) to integrate the credit card form on the checkout page. Before I used stripe.checkout.sessions.create({}) which redirected to the standard-checkout page provided by stripe. Using that checkout I found a checkout summary with a subscription reference.

Does anybody know what the reason for the missing checkout summary could be?

I checked the error log and response data. These include all the details for the payment plan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I have an assumption that this data is only created when paying through an external form